# Why do I get a type error when trying to set a variable using a loop?

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I am trying to set a variable for each row based on a if statements, each row needs to have its own value based on the conditions. The purpose of which is to back test a pricing indicator. I am able to set df_main to only consider the last row which works however I need a result for each row to back test.

The error i receive is:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

```
maximum_long=df_main[df_main.columns[i]].max()              # find extremes of all positions and traders
minimum_long=df_main[df_main.columns[i]].min()

maximum_short=df_main[df_main.columns[i+1]].min()
minimum_short=df_main[df_main.columns[i+1]].max()    

maximum_trader_long=df_main[df_main.columns[i+2]].max()
minimum_trader_long=df_main[df_main.columns[i+2]].min()  

maximum_trader_short=df_main[df_main.columns[i+3]].max()
minimum_trader_short=df_main[df_main.columns[i+3]].min() 

long_quartile= (maximum_long - minimum_long)/4              #Create quartiles for short and long positions
short_quartile= (maximum_short - minimum_short)/4

trader_long_quartile= (maximum_trader_long - minimum_trader_long)/4
trader_short_quartile= (maximum_trader_short - minimum_trader_short)/4

df_main['dry_long_score'] = 0
df_main['dry_short_score'] = 0

for index, rows in df_main.iterrows():

    if df_main.columns[i] > minimum_long + 3*long_quartile:
        if df_main.columns[i+2]> minimum_trader_long + 3*trader_long_quartile:
            df_main['dry_long_score']=-1
        else:
            df_main['dry_long_score']=0
    elif long_commitment_last < minimum_long + long_quartile:     
        if df_main.columns[i+2]< minimum_trader_long + trader_long_quartile:  
            df_main['dry_long_score']=1
        else:
            df_main['dry_long_score']=0
    else:
        df_main['dry_long_score']=0 

    if df_main.columns[i+1] < minimum_short + 3*short_quartile:
        if df_main.columns[i+3]> minimum_trader_short + 3*trader_long_quartile:
            df_main['dry_short_score']=1
        else:
            df_main['dry_short_score']=0
    elif df_main.columns[i+1] < minimum_short + short_quartile:     
        if df_main.columns[i+3]< minimum_trader_short + trader_short_quartile:  
            df_main['dry_short_score']=-1
        else:
            df_main['dry_short_score']=0
    else:
        df_main['dry_short_score']=0      


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-01e4e50d5411> in <module>()
     23 for index, rows in df_main.iterrows():
     24 
---> 25     if df_main.columns[i] > minimum_long + 3*long_quartile:
     26         if df_main.columns[i+2]> minimum_trader_long + 3*trader_long_quartile:
     27             df_main['dry_long_score']=-1

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if df_main.columns[i] > minimum_long + 3*long_quartile:
```

In this line, the left is a columns of dataframe but the right is a number. So you can't compare between array and number. Therefore, here throw a type error.

Comment: I think you can use max() or min() on left, make array be number